# Tkinter Text Widget Line By Line Colorizing Animation

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I want to create an animation where every line of a text widget is highlighted for 0.5 seconds. I figured out that this can be done by using tags.

```
root = Tk()
text = Text(root,width=28, height=20)
text.pack()
for i in range(int(text.index('end-1c').split('.')[0])):
    text.tag_add("Tag", f"{i + 1}.0", f"{i + 1}.0+1lines")
    text.tag_config("Tag", background="khaki")
    #Some waiting for 0.5 seconds
    text.tag_remove("Tag",f"{i + 1}.0", f"{i + 1}.0+1lines")
root.mainloop()
```

I tried `time.slepp` already but this does not work (It just freezes the screen).

I know there is some way in `tkinter` to do this but I could not find any solution or answer on the internet.

Comment: You can put thin in a function and run that function in another thread. That way the main thread running the gui loop is free to react on user-interaction

Comment: @DwightFromTheOffice You mean to run it recursively? Or how would it look like?

Comment: @DwightFromTheOffice That isn't good. `tkinter` isn't threadsafe so you shouldn't call it from different threads.

Comment: @PucciLaCanton Look at `.after` scripts.

Comment: @TheLizzard I tried this too and used it successfully in another function but in this case it does not work. But i can try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk


def function(i=0):
    text.tag_remove("Tag", "0.0", "end")

    # If we reached the end, stop
    if i == int(text.index("end-1c").split(".")[0]):
        return None

    text.tag_add("Tag", f"{i + 1}.0", f"{i + 1}.0+1lines")

    # After 0.5 sec run the function again with i = i + 1
    text.after(500, function, i+1)


root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()
text.insert("end", "\n".join(map(str, range(10))))
text.tag_config("Tag", background="red")

button = tk.Button(root, text="Click me", command=function)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

It uses a `for` loop implemented using `.after` scripts. Each time it calls `function` with `i` being incremented, where the default value for `i` is 0.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know now why it seemed to that it does not work. I removed the tag before the `after` method. Hahah it was a dumb mistake.

Comment: @PucciLaCanton :D Little mistakes can cause headaches.